# 3D Touch shortcut menu not redirecting to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3dtouch

I'm using objective-c to create the 3D touch shortcut menu. I have followed this example https://github.com/dakeshi/3D_Touch_HomeQuickAction of how to do it and looked at swift tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO9E5KxixOw  of how to implement this but still having issues with it.

The shortcut menu shows perfectly however upon tapping one of the items it takes me to the home page of the app and not to the view i have specified.

Below is the code used in my app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Check API availiability
// UIApplicationShortcutItem is available in iOS 9 or later.
if([[UIApplicationShortcutItem class] respondsToSelector:@selector(new)]){

    [self configDynamicShortcutItems];

    // If a shortcut was launched, display its information and take the appropriate action
    UIApplicationShortcutItem *shortcutItem = [launchOptions objectForKeyedSubscript:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey];

    if(shortcutItem)
    {
        // When the app launch at first time, this block can not called.

        [self handleShortCutItem:shortcutItem];

        // This will block "performActionForShortcutItem:completionHandler" from being called.
        shouldPerformAdditionalDelegateHandling = NO;


    }
}
 return shouldPerformAdditionalDelegateHandling;

- (void)configDynamicShortcutItems {

// config image shortcut items
// if you want to use custom image in app bundles, use iconWithTemplateImageName method
UIApplicationShortcutIcon *shortcutSearchIcon = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithType:UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeBookmark];
UIApplicationShortcutIcon *shortcutFavoriteIcon = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithType:UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeBookmark];

UIApplicationShortcutItem *shortcutSearch = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc]
                                             initWithType:@"com.sarangbang.QuickAction.Search"
                                             localizedTitle:@"Events"
                                             localizedSubtitle:nil
                                             icon:shortcutSearchIcon
                                             userInfo:nil];

UIApplicationShortcutItem *shortcutFavorite = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc]
                                               initWithType:@"com.sarangbang.QuickAction.Favorite"
                                               localizedTitle:@"Latest News"
                                               localizedSubtitle:nil
                                               icon:shortcutFavoriteIcon
                                               userInfo:nil];


// add all items to an array
NSArray *items = @[shortcutSearch, shortcutFavorite];

// add the array to our app
[UIApplication sharedApplication].shortcutItems = items;
}

- (BOOL)handleShortCutItem : (UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem{

    BOOL handled = NO;

    NSString *bundleId = [NSBundle mainBundle].bundleIdentifier;

    NSString *shortcutSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.Search", bundleId];
    NSString *shortcutFavorite = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.Favorite", bundleId];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];


    if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:shortcutSearch]) {
        handled = YES;

        EventsViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EventsViewController"];

        UINavigationController *navController;
[navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

        self.window.rootViewController = vc;

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    }

    else if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:shortcutFavorite]) {
        handled = YES;

        NewsViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsViewController"];

        self.window.rootViewController = vc;

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }


    return handled;
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler{

BOOL handledShortCutItem = [self handleShortCutItem:shortcutItem];

completionHandler(handledShortCutItem);
}
```

Comment: What are the results of debugging? Is the program going into the correct if? Does `vc` holds the correct view controller after the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` call?

Comment: Ok I figured it out eventually. It turned out that the bundle identifier was wrong in my `initWithType`. It should be `com.yoursite.yourapp.value`